# How to make separate sessions in chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, client-side

Imagine having two tabs open in chrome. They are both open on youtube.com. They are signed into two different youtube accounts with different cookies simultaneously.

This is the experience offered by sessionbox.io in tabbed session management. I'm just wondering how this is possible? No cookies are stored or accessible in my local storage or cookie storage (inspect element in tab or extension).

My question:
How are the different cookies managed in the tabs to create two different session experiences?